# Android sqlite read and compare question

Tags: java, sql, android, compare

I have a simple sample game that has a menu with buttons to all levels. I wanted to have it where only level 1 is "unlocked" or clickable and the user unlocks the levels 1 by 1. So, i've thought about using preferences and setting a boolean property to each level but I also wanted to learn SQL and so, implemented it into the game. Now I can add values into the database but when reading them back and comparing them to a string it's not doing anything:

```
public String getValue(Cursor cursor) {
    String id = new String();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        id = cursor.getString(0);
    }
    return id;
}
```

I then compare it using string.toString().equals("something"); Is there a better way of doing what I would like to do? and why does it not compare?

Comment: What is `string.toString().equals("something")`. What's `string`? Where are you using it? What is it returning? What is the value of `id` that that function returns? What do you expect it to "do"?

Comment: string is a String object and during some searching many people have said to use toString().equals("");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Why not just store the last level they unlocked, instead of each one?  If they unlocked level 3 doesn't it mean they also have levels 1 and 2 unlocked?  Or am I misunderstanding?
2. You realize string.toString() doesn't do anything right?  It's already a String.
3. You're looping through the entire Cursor and only returning the last result.  You could just jump to the last result, or better yet just select the last row in the table.  Your code is extremely inefficient.
4. Show more of the code around the call to .equals("something") you may have a problem there.

> why does it not compare?

Have you tried debugging the code or at least printing out the value of the string to make sure it contains the value you think it contains?  I'm pretty sure there isn't a bug in the implementation of String.equals() so I'd say the string you are comparing against doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: 1. Agreed, 2: As I thought, but I was doing it according to all the sample code people have posted, 3. There are many more results but I just simplified and took out everything not needed, 4. Will do.

Comment: Regarding #3, the entire for loop is unneeded and makes your code inefficient.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Almost every example i've gone through has it implemented as so.

Comment: You would only implement it that way if you wanted to return more than one result, say a List or Array, which is probably what most of the examples are doing.  I highly recommend you learn some more of the basics of Java and programming in general so that you understand what you are doing before trying to tackle writing an Android app.